# Issues in Upgrading Struts 2.1 to 2.3.15.1

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2, jar

Due to the recent security vulnerability identified in Struts, I'm upgrading my web application to Struts 2.3.15.1.
The Application is up and running but I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/logging/Logger.debug(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.populateComponentHtmlId(UIBean.java:992)
at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:801)
at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:523)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
at com.ibm._jsp._Messages._jspx_meth_s_actionmessage_0(_Messages.java:193)
at com.ibm._jsp._Messages._jspx_meth_s_if_1(_Messages.java:226)
at com.ibm._jsp._Messages._jspService(_Messages.java:98)
```

I do have the xwork-2.1.2.jar and other required jar files in web-inf/lib folder inside the EAR.
This exception is shown in the UI when I'm setting success/error message using the `addActionMessage()` method after a save/delete is performed via AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the version mismatch error, mixing libraries from different versions of framework will cause unsuspected incompatibilities in the code. Make sure you copy the libraries from the one distro or version of Struts. If you are using maven then update the versions of Struts2 dependencies to correspond the version you use or use `struts2-core` artifact to fetch up all required dependencies.